# Error when building Docker image from React and Nodejs app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, dockerfile

I`ve built a small react and node js app and I would like to build from it a docker image.

This is the Dockerfile that I`ve build:

```
FROM node:10 AS ui-build
WORKDIR /react-express-example/client/src
COPY client/ ./client/
RUN cd client && npm install && npm run build

FROM node:10 AS server-build
WORKDIR /react-express-example/
COPY --from=ui-build /client/src ./client/src
COPY /react-express-example/package*.json ./react-express-example/
RUN cd react-express-example && npm install
COPY /react-express-example/index.js ./react-express-example/

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["node", "./react-express-example/index.js"]
```

This is the file path for the app:

The whole app: C:\nodejs\react-express-example
The react app: C:\nodejs\react-express-example\client

When I build the image with the command: docker -t build react-node-image . I get the error:

> => ERROR [server-build 6/6] COPY /react-express-example/index.js ./react-express-example/                         0.0s

---

> [server-build 6/6] COPY /react-express-example/index.js ./react-express-example/:

---

> failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: failed to compute cache key: "/react-express-example/index.js" not found: not found

I am a beginner can please someone help me with writing the Dockerfile correctly according to the path that I`ve given ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the Dockerfile in the `react-express-example` directory, or in the parent `nodejs` directory?

Comment: react-express-example is the parent directory that holds the react app and the node app and it also holds the Dockerfile

Comment: If the `Dockerfile`, server application, and the `client` subdirectory are all in the same place then you need to `COPY package*.json ./` without including the parent directory's name.  All of the paths in the first half of `COPY` directives are relative to the directory you name in the `docker build` command.